# popup page is not redirecting right page

Tags: c#

On home page if I do login ,so after login I will redirect in dashboard page that placed in one folder.
So after login page ,I am calling a popup page on button click by below c# code that page is in root folder.i am using below code on button click.

```
    protected void LBDmss_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", "var Mleft = (screen.width/2)-(760/2);var Mtop = (screen.height/2)-(700/2);window.open( 'DMSSView.aspx', null, 'height=700,width=760,status=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,location=no,top=\'+Mtop+\', left=\'+Mleft+\'' );", true);


    }
```

But on popup window it is not redirecting page .it is merging parent page folder path with this page's given path. Perhaps just because of session variable it is taking parent page path.
So page doesn't open because path is wrong.
Please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this: (`../../`) or (`../`).

```
protected void LBDmss_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OPEN_WINDOW", "var Mleft = (screen.width/2)-(760/2);var Mtop = (screen.height/2)-(700/2);window.open( '../../DMSSView.aspx', null, 'height=700,width=760,status=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,location=no,top=\'+Mtop+\', left=\'+Mleft+\'' );", true);


    }
```

Comment: Glad to see it helps you! Enjoy! :)